# .cs File Has Â Instead of Spaces

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I've got a project with a .cs file with a weird encoding issue.

Visual Studio has no problem with it, but once I tried using a 3rd party tool for static analysis, it immediately croaked with a parse error.

Using a hex editor I opened the file in question and discovered this (just showing a snippet, but the whole file is like this):

```
Â Â Â Â public class CacheCommandElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection..Â Â Â Â {..Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â
```

I'm sure the garbage character would show up differently with other encodings...

No other files in that particular folder exhibit the same behavior, but I'm sure there are more peppered throughout the solution.

I've got a script to change all .cs files to UTF8 encoding, but that alone doesn't strip out the garbage character, and neither does `.Replace("Â", string.Empty)`

Any idea how I can purge this character out of my source files?

Comment: Try to use Find and Replace from Visual Studio.

Comment: You can't see it in Visual Studio, it looks like a space.

Comment: Why don't you create a little C# program, that opens this file using the `StreamReader` with the ASCII encoding, replaces the char and then writes it back?

Comment: If you can't see it in Visual Studio, then also try to replace it using Find and Replace. It doesn't mean that if you can't see it, then it does not reside there. If you don't find anything in Visual Studio using Find and Replace then your file is clean. I think so.... Or you might select that invisible character and copy it and then try to paste it in Find TextBox and then again try to replace it.

Comment: @Vishal: I did try it (just to humor you), none of that works.

Comment: @Dmitry: no good, it doesn't find the character to replace.

Comment: If you open this .cs file in MS-Word or any other program then, you might be able to see that character there. If you see it there, then try to use find and replace in that program. Or you should try to follow @Dmitry.

Comment: @Vishal: you're right, I could open it in Word and probably fix it. Notepad also works. The problem is beyond just fixing this one file, I need to script a solution to fix potentially hundreds of files.

Comment: Then you should try a solution given by @Dmitry

Comment: See above. I did, it didn't work. Probably because .Net strings are encoded a particular way in memory that precludes the possibility of finding that particular character.

Comment: if you open the file in VS with the binary editor what is the value of the space. a default project has 20 (hex) as the value of all spaces.

Comment: I didn't think of that... The spaces displays as dots, and alternate between `C2` and `A0`.

Comment: @Anders use those hex values in your Replace deal. like maybe `char r1 = 0xc2 , r2 = 0xa0;` then pass to replace

Comment: I'll give it a shot - I don't think I can assign a char value directly like that, but there should be an easy conversion.

Comment: That's working great - put that in an answer and I'll mark it resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source file is in UTF-8, the code in indented using non-breaking spaces. That third-party tool either reads the code with incorrect encoding, or doesn't support non-ASCII whitespace.

According to the spec, you can use non-breaking spaces in C#.

If you can, try configuring the tool to use UTF-8 for the source encoding. If it's impossible, or it doesn't work, you can simply replace all those non-breaking spaces with normal spaces.

`Â` is bytes `c2 a0` (non-breaking space in UTF-8) interpreted in Windows-1252 or Windows-1250. The second character displayed here is again a non-breaking space.

You can also fix it by using Visual Studio to auto-reformat all the code, or to use built-in search-and-replace function to replace all non-breaking spaces with normal spaces (you can copy the non-breaking space from the source).